# update list dbref inside collection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

i have a catalog collection that has a list of product, i want to update the catalog by adding another product, the problem is that in the catalog collection it deletes the existing products and leaves the added one, while in the product collection they are still existing

```
@Document(collection = "catalog")
public class Catalog {

    @Id
    String id;
    String name;
    @DBRef
    List<Product> products;
}

@Document(collection = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    String id;
    Integer price;
}

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        return args -> {
            // step 1
            List<Product> products1 = Arrays.asList(new Product().id("1").price(120), new Product().id("2").price(150));
            for (Product product : products1) {
                mongoOperations.save(product);
            }
            mongoOperations.save(new Catalog().id("55").name("Catalog 1").products(products1));

            // step 2
            List<Product> products2 = Arrays.asList(new Product().id("3").price(497));
            for (Product product : products2) {
                mongoOperations.save(product);
            }
            mongoOperations.save(new Catalog().id("55").name("Catalog 1").products(products2));
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spring javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#save-T-) save method does the following: *Save the object to the collection for the entity type of the object to save. This will perform an insert if the object is not already present, that is an 'upsert'.*